# How can I get my intent back from a service that is started by the AlarmManager?

Tags: android, service, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I use an alarm service to jump to a service. when the service starts, hwo can I get the intent back(I want to get data from the intent)?
My code is as follows

```
PendingIntent sender=PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

How do I get "myIntent" back from the service? there's no method such like getIntent()
in service. I tried to use the intent in onBind(Intent intent), but it is not what I want.

---

I think I got this porblem solved.
PendingIntent sender=PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 
                                              PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

the problem is about the flag. now I can get my intent back at the service class
OnStartCommand(Intent,int,int)

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense at all. Adding that flag should make absolutely no change at all. This is misleading at best.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get "myIntent" back from the service?

It is passed as a parameter to `onStartCommand()` (and, if this is an `IntentService`, also to `onHandleIntent()`).

Comment: yeah, before I change the flag from 0 to PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
I failed to get intent back from onStartCommand.
thank you , anyway